# AWS GLUE error crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-crawler, etl, aws-glue

I run a crawler and it gives me the following error:

> Some files do not match the schema detected. Remove or exclude the
>   following files from the crawler:

These files are compressed with `gz` and are located in `s3`.
All the files have the same format, for example:

`MSC,LL,150635,1142323,702551687172,,,,,,,,20170207,000356,0,MAD06Q1 1R15AI0,EAIMX2I,,,,,,,,,1,0,2,`

Any ideas on how to fix this error please?

Comment: Could you please share the cloudwatch logs for crawler?

Comment: If I make a custom classifier this problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: Hi Am facing the same error message while trying to crawl some log files which are in S3, the files are in csv format.  Can you please tell me how did you resolve using the custom classifier?  Also on what scenario this error occurs?